# Add Class on commented code or conditional code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conditional-statements, conditional-comments

Is possible manage conditional code by jQuery or javascript

```
<!--[if IE]>
<div class="ie">IE ALERT</div>
<![endif]-->

$('.ie').addClass('ie-additional-class');
```

The [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/p3ojxjz1/).

Comment: Your fiddle doesn’t match your code snippet. Do you want to display an element for all browsers and add a class only in IE? Or do you only want to display an element for IE and add a class to it?

Comment: fiddle is just example -  I need to add class inside conditional code

Comment: Your fiddle uses `<![if IE]>` and your code snippet uses `<!--[if IE]>`. The first of these is useless, so I’ll just assume you’re actually using the second. `$('.ie').addClass('ie-additional-class');` should work fine. If it doesn’t, please make a JSFiddle that actually represents the bug.